# Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: java, automation, appium

I am not able to run the automation script that was running earlier. When i try to run the same code in new device its works fine.

**Appium Server Log**

> [UiAutomator2] Running command: 'adb -s K3V4C18B16002502 shell am
>   instrument -w
>   io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
>   [UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 20000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
>   [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
>   [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] android.util.AndroidException:
>   INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED:
>   io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
>   [debug] [UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS:
>   Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for:
>   ComponentInfo{io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
>   [debug] [UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS:
>   id=ActivityManagerService [debug] [UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2]
>   INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1 [debug] [UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2]
>     at com.android.commands.am.Instrument.run(Instrument.java:486)
>   [debug] [UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2]     at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:194) [debug]
>   [UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2]     at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:80) [debug] [UiAutomator2]
>   [UIAutomator2]    at
>   com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:54) [debug]
>   [UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2]     at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:50) [debug] [UiAutomator2]
>   [UIAutomator2]    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>   [debug] [UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2]     at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:371) [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus' [debug]
>   [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET
>   http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body [JSONWP Proxy] Got
>   an unexpected response:
>   {"errno":"ECONNRESET","code":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"} [debug]
>   [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session [debug] [UiAutomator2]
>   Deleting UiAutomator2 server session [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched
>   '/' to command name 'deleteSession' [UiAutomator2] Did not get
>   confirmation UiAutomator2 deleteSession worked; Error was:
>   UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing
>   the command. Original error: Trying to proxy a session command without
>   session id [debug] [UiAutomator2] Resetting IME to
>   'com.touchtype.swiftkey/com.touchtype.KeyboardService' [debug] [ADB]
>   Running '/Users/infotmt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037
>   -s K3V4C18B16002402 shell ime set com.touchtype.swiftkey/com.touchtype.KeyboardService' [debug] [ADB]
>   Running '/Users/infotmt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037
>   -s K3V4C18B16002402 shell am force-stop eu.niko.smart.naswi.personalization' [debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat
>   capture [debug] [ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200 
>   [debug] [ADB] Running
>   '/Users/infotmt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s
>   K3V4C18B16002402 forward --remove tcp:8200' [debug] [ADB] Device API
>   level: 28 [UiAutomator2] Restoring hidden api policy to the device
>   default configuration [debug] [ADB] Running
>   '/Users/infotmt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s
>   K3V4C18B16002402 shell settings delete global
>   hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps' [debug] [ADB] Running
>   '/Users/infotmt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s
>   K3V4C18B16002402 shell settings delete global
>   hidden_api_policy_p_apps' [debug] [BaseDriver] Event
>   'newSessionStarted' logged at 1549963457849 (15:09:17 GMT+0545 (Nepal
>   Time)) [debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command:
>   UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing
>   the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server.
>   Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET [debug] [W3C]     at
>   JWProxy.command
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:236:13)
>   [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 50913 ms - 532

**Java error log**

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new
>   remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original
>   error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
>   command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server.
>   Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET Build info: version:
>   '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System
>   info: host: 'Suban12.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:486:de1:7ae1:b02d%en0',
>   os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_202' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>   remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred
>   while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command
>   to remote server. Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at JWProxy.command (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:236:13)
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'Suban12.local', ip:
>   'fe80:0:0:0:486:de1:7ae1:b02d%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
>   'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '1.8.0_202' Driver
>   info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>
> at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:84)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:94)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:95)
>     at util.AppiumHelper.setupPersDriver(AppiumHelper.java:74)  at
>   test_cases.PersHelper.startPersAppReset(PersHelper.java:21)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
>     ... 38 more Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An
>   unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original
>   error: Error: read ECONNRESET Build info: version: '3.141.59',
>   revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host:
>   'Suban12.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:486:de1:7ae1:b02d%en0', os.name: 'Mac
>   OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_202' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver remote
>   stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while
>   processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to
>   remote server. Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at JWProxy.command (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:236:13)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>     at
>   java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
>     ... 43 more

Comment: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT                    
       I get  this during parallel run on iOS simulators an attempt to type  some string in input fields

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem. The solution is to remove **io.appium.uiautomator2.server** and **io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test** from the device.

1. Make sure appium server is not executing.
2. Connect your android device with USB,  also verify that device is connected properly by using command:

   ```
   adb devices
   ```
3. Execute below commands:

   ```
   adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
   adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
   ```
4. Start appium server
5. Start executing appium test cases

Comment: This did not resolve my problem. I am getting this when running tests in parallel, any help?

Comment: I'm facing same issue in iOS ? any help ?

Comment: this helps when the socket hangs up.

Comment: My issue got resolved after using these commands, thanks mate.

Comment: it would be great if someone could explain why this is happening, and how the fix works

Answer (score 1):

I have uninstalled below app(manually) from emulator which solved the problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `newCommandTimeout` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just kill all the Appium processes.
Enter this command in terminal
`taskkill /F /IM node.exe`